# При открытие url сервер должен выдавать другую страницу - htaccess и rewriterule и wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Доброго часа) Сайт сделан на **WordPress** и к нему подключен плагин который называется `web-camera (Автор: Denis Bogdanov)` (расположен `/wp-content/plugins/web-camera/`). Адрес ссылки для отображения контента `http://test.ru/web-camera/` (`http://test.ru/web-camera/primer1/` - ссылка на страницу с камерой).

> Необходимо, что бы контент содержащийся по этому адресу отображался по адресу: `http://test.ru/camera/` (`http://test.ru/camera/primer1/` - ссылка на страницу с камерой).

Я пробовал переименовать папку с плагином и изменить пути к css и js файлам, и после этих манипуляций все равно открывается плагин по адресу `http://test.ru/web-camera/` (хотя физически на сервере он уже расположен по адресу `/wp-content/plugins/camera/`). Есть предположение, что решить эту проблему можно с помощью **RewriteEngine**, но сам, к сожалению, так и не разобрался как правильно прописать правила в файле .htaccess.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему? Возможно надо что то в самом WordPress отредактировать или плагине. Я не пользовался движками, поэтом не очень понимаю как в них работают плагины.

Заранее всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: дайте линк на плагин.

Answer (score 1):

можите написать в htaccess такое правило, должно сработать

```
RewriteRule ^camera/    /web-camera/primer1/ [QSA,L]
```

слева адрес на котором должно отображатся данные с правого адреса

Comment: Я делал вот так `RewriteRule ^camera/(.*)$ /web-camera/$1 [QSA,L]`, но в таком случае переадресует на андрес `/web-camera/$1`, а мне нужно что бы адрес оставлся прежним, т.е. `camera/$1`, но подгружалась страница с адреса `/web-camera/$1`.